# Multiple Choice questions with radio buttons in one method not working

Tags: java, android

This is likely not the best way to accomplish the following goal, I'm aware of that and open to any suggestions.

Goal: Create multiple choice / true false style questions in succeeding order in the same activity.

Ideal state: The above in a reusable class. (I have failed to accomplish this because of the necessity of (findViewById) in code below)

Problem: Quiz logic does not work. Question 1 will accept the correct answer but will not change the result text appropriately on correct answer, but will change all to Try Again. Question 2 will not accept an

Things I have attempted: For, while, switch - all set up in similar manners.

```
public void onClickListenerQuestion0(){

    btnGetStartedReviewSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int questionNumber = 0;

            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
            int selection = radioGroupGetStartedReview.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            radio_button = (RadioButton) findViewById(selection);
              if (questionNumber==0) {
                  if (selection == R.id.radioGetStartedReview3) {
                      textGetStartedReviewResult.setText("Correct!");
                      Toast.makeText(GetStarted.this, "Great job. Here's the next question.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      textGetStartedReviewQuestion.setText("This is question 2!");
                      radioGetStartedReview0.setText("True");
                      radioGetStartedReview1.setText("False");
                      radioGetStartedReview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      radioGetStartedReview3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      questionNumber++;
                  } else {
                      textGetStartedReviewResult.setText("Try Again.");
                  } //end else
              }
              if (questionNumber==1) {
                  if (selection == R.id.radioGetStartedReview1) {
                      textGetStartedReviewResult.setText("That's right!");
                      btnGetStartedReviewContinue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      btnGetStartedReviewSubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  } else {
                      textGetStartedReviewResult.setText("Try Again.");
                  }//end else
              }
            }
        }
    }); //end onClickListener

}
```

Honestly the whole thing feels sloppy. I like the look of the transition between different activities and would love to see something similar happen in the text here rather than just invisible to visible.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When you have variable names that end with a number, you should consider using an array or `List` instead.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks. I'm not sure an array would resolve the problem here though.

Comment: This will help because you can use a counter to determine which question you are on. If done well, you can pretty much eliminate all of the `if` statements.

Comment: I suggest that you use the debugger in Android Studio to step through your code to determine what it is doing.

Comment: I highly suggest attempting to build this in plain old java before adding the complexity of any UI to it.  Building this in Java will help you focus on the lifecycle of a given question first.

Comment: @eddiecubed The problem for me there is the inclusion of the findViewById component. I can't get it to work in a standalone class without having this present in an actual activity

Comment: findViewById() is specific to the android graphics framework.  When you have a sound flow for your questions, building the UI will come more naturally.

As for your difficulties with building a more reactive UI; Try building a few methods which populate the view and clear the view.  From there you will slowly build helper methods to add text, add listeners to aide you in your questionnaire project.

Comment: One last thing.  what have you tried searching for online?  I would bet you could find a wonderful tutorial on how to make a quiz game or questionnaire.

Comment: Most of the items I have found while searching online have actually use Buttons/ImageButtons instead of radio buttons as they seem inherently complicated.

Comment: Did my answer help you?  Did it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The following should give you some guided direction to build a UI that can help you more with your questionnaire.  We are marking use of the RadioGroup widget here.  With RadioGroup, you can traverse the child objects.  In this case, I have several RadioButtons within the RadioGroup.  The following is the simple RadioGroup for example:

```
    <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New RadioButton"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

RadioGroup has some nice helper methods to traverse the child views.  You can expand on this by giving the RadioGroup a max number of buttons, or even get really fancy and add them dynamically in your code.

My comments within the code should give you enough direction to know where to inject the question presenter logic.

```
/**
 * Our RadioGroup
 */
RadioGroup radioGroup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //gather our reference to the RadioGroup
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(radioListener);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //build our first question
    buildQuestion(0);
}

/**
 * This is how we will capture our User's response.  Once they click on a radio button,
 * the response can immediately be checked if it is correct.
 * <p/>
 * we can modify the accessor method submitAnswer(int) to be something like collectAnswer(int) instead.
 * Then with the use of a button on the screen which the user can use to submit their answer.
 */
RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener radioListener = new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch (checkedId) {
            default:
                Log.w(TAG, "No Support for questions with more than 4 possible answers. checkId: " + checkedId);
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton4:
                Log.i(TAG, "Button 4");
                submitAnswer(3);
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton3:
                Log.i(TAG, "Button 3");
                submitAnswer(2);
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton2:
                Log.i(TAG, "Button 2");
                submitAnswer(1);
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton:
                Log.i(TAG, "Button 1");
                submitAnswer(0);
                break;
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Build and Display question for user.
 *
 * @param question the position which question whould be shown to the user.
 */
private void buildQuestion(int question) {
    //this method would set and display your question
    displayQuestionText(question);

    //this would gather your answers to display to your user.
    String[] orderedAnswers = displayPossibleAnswers(question);

    for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View o = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (o instanceof RadioButton) {
            if(i < orderedAnswers.length) {
                ((RadioButton) o).setText(orderedAnswers[i]);
                ((RadioButton) o).setVisibility(View.Visible);                
            } else {
                ((RadioButton) o).setText("");
                ((RadioButton) o).setVisibility(View.Gone);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Submit user's answer.  This also handles the return of checking answer to display to the user
 * whether they got the question correct or incorrect.
 *
 * @param i position of user's answer
 */
private void submitAnswer(int i) {
    //some method to check if this is the right answer
    if (checkAnswer(i)) {
        //user selected correct answer
        textGetStartedReviewResult.setText("Correct!");
        Toast.makeText(GetStarted.this, "Great job. Here's the next question.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        buildQuestion(getNextQuestion());
    } else {
        //user was incorrect.  Say something encouraging to them.
        textGetStartedReviewResult.setText("Try Again.");
    }
}
```